# Need help calling function in my hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Need help calling function in my python game.

I'm working on my first Python Hangman game using `turtle`. I just need to figure out a way to call the below function when a user inputs the incorrect character.

```
def drawHangman(counter):

  def drawNoose():
    turtle.speed(10)
    turtle.color("Black")
    turtle.forward(120)
    turtle.forward(-60)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawHead():
    turtle.circle(15)
    turtle.circle(15, 180) # draw a semicircle
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawArms():
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.forward(-40)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawTorso():
    turtle.forward(30)

  def drawLegs():
    turtle.left(45)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.forward(-30)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.forward(-30)
    turtle.left(45)

  if counter==0:
    drawNoose()
  elif counter==1:
    drawNoose()
    drawHead()
  elif counte)
  elif counter==4:
    drawLegs()r==2:
    drawArms()
  elif counter==3:
    drawTorso)
  elif counter==4:
    drawLegs()()
  elif counter==4:
    drawLegs()
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

My code is below:

```
guesses = ''

turns = 6

while turns > 0:


    failed = 0


    for char in word:


        if char in guesses:
            print(char)

        else:
            print("_")



            failed +=1



    if failed == 0:

        print("You Win")


        print("The word is: ", word)
        break


    guess = input("guess a character:")


    guesses += guess


    if guess not in word:

        turns -= 1


        print("Wrong")





        print("You have", + turns, 'more guesses')

        if turns == 0:
            print("You Loose")
```

Comment: Please me more spefic with your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site to read through your code. The relevant parts should be included _here_, as part of your question, ideally as a [mcve].

Comment: how should be that error do you wan't

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You csn use

```
def drawHangman(counter):

  def drawNoose():
    turtle.speed(10)
    turtle.color("Black")
    turtle.forward(120)
    turtle.forward(-60)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawHead():
    turtle.circle(15)
    turtle.circle(15, 180) # draw a semicircle
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawArms():
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.forward(-40)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)

  def drawTorso():
    turtle.forward(30)

  def drawLegs():
    turtle.left(45)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.forward(-30)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.forward(-30)
    turtle.left(45)

  if counter==0:
    drawNoose()
  elif counter==1:
    drawNoose()
    drawHead()
  elif counter==2:
    drawArms()
  elif counter==3:
    drawTorso()
  elif counter==4:
    drawLegs()
```

this function(the same as your sample link)

and then call this function like `drawHangman()` you can use it in line 86 of your code.

and also you have a `failed` variable; you can put this variable into the input of function `drawHangman()` like `drawHangman(failed)`